# График и интервалы

Tags: php, html, javascript, css

Суть задачи. Дано n-ое число интервалов времени. К примеру: 13.20-13.50, 13.10-14.00 и т.д. Интервалы могут пересекаться. Нужно вывести в график эти интервалы с отображением пересечений. 
Моя проблема: если только 2 пересечения, то я могу представить это. А если больше 2, то не могу представить себе график, как это выглядеть должно.
Если знаете как это должно выглядеть, то отпишитесь либо ссылку дайте. Не могу себе именно график представить. С кодом уж потом как-нибудь. 
спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Каждый интервал представлен на диаграмме прямоугольником. Непересекающиеся интервалы могут иметь одинаковую высоту, и цвет. Если несколько интервалов пересекаются, то каждый из них должен иметь свой цвет и высоту, так, чтобы каждый из них был отличим от других. Пересечения визуализируются с помощью выбора нужного режима смешения цветов (blending mode) и заданием компонента прозрачности (alpha). Примерно представить себе, как это будет выглядеть, можно на примере нижеследующей иллюстрации:

[image: Пересекающиеся окружности]

Как видите, на экране множество окружностей и многие их них неоднократно пересекаются, но, тем не менее, границы каждого достаточно легко различимы.

В браузере это сложно сделать, тем более, кроссбраузерным путем. Можно попробовать библиотечку [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/), которая рендерит графику через SVG на тех браузерах, которые его поддерживают, и через VML в IE, и позволяет установить свойство "opacity" для геометрических объектов. Вообще, сложные графики и диаграммы обычно строятся на сервере, клиенту отдается готовый результат в виде изображений PNG, JPEG и т.д. На сервере нет ограничений, присущих браузерной среде, можно использовать развитые библиотеки для работы с изображениями. К примеру, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), который имеет [кучу биндингов](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) к самым различным языкам, включая PHP.

Comment: Я вот смотрел разные строители графиков, не нашел где можно подобное сделать. Это самому надо все строить либо просто разобраться надо в строителях? И если знаете, с помощью какой библиотеки такое точно можно сделать.
За рисунок спасибо, очень наглядный.

Comment: Дополнил ответ по вашим вопросам.

Comment: спасибо большое, буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

если отбросить смешение цветов при пересечении фигур, то может справиться с такой задачей библиотечка FLOT - http://code.google.com/p/flot/
там хорошо реализовано представление оси Х во временном формате.